# How to open compiled app with read and write permissions?

Tags: bash, qt, sh

I need to write a .sh script that is doing 3 things - compile and run app, compile unit tests and run those in console and create test coverage raport. Both test parts are working, but there is a problem after opening main app. It seems that it can't open / read / write into external files, even simple text files. Problem doesn't exist when I run compiled file manually (via console command "./appname"). In script I'm using the same command. App is written in Qt C++ framework, operating system is ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you open your file? if, you are using relative paths in your app and the current directory is different between your script and your command line, it will not work.

Comment: thanks, that was the cause.